# Django templates {% include %} fallback value

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to dynamically load a template like so:

```
{% include 'some-folder/'|add:var|add:'.html' %}
```

But these templates are not always present. So I would like to add a fallback value/default template to be loaded if one being requested is not found.

Is this possible? If not (out-of-the-box), how can I write a custom templatetag that does so?

Answer (score 0):

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_template_path(var1, var2):
    template_path = 'some-folder/' + var1 + '/' + var2 + '.html'
    default_template = 'some-folder/default_template.html'
    try:
       template.loader.get_template(template_path)
       return template_path
    except TemplateDoesNotExist:
       return default_template

In template call this template tag like this:

{% load get_template_path %}
{% get_template_path var1='qq' var2='ee' as temlate_path %}
{% include template_path %}
```

Comment: This isn't a filter, so can't be handed to include. All this does is print a path.